# Python 3, extract info from file problems

Tags: file, python-3.x, edit, expect, xlwt

And again, asking for help. But, before I start, here will be a lot of text, so please sorry for that.
I have about 500~ IP addresses with devices 2x categories in .xlsx book
I want:
telnet to device. Check device (by authentication prompt) type 1 or type 2.

If device is type 1 - get it firmware version in 2x partitions
write in excel file: 
column 1 - IP address
column 2 - device type
column 3 - firmware version
column 4 - firmware version in reserve partition.

If type 2 - write in excel file:
column 1 - IP address
column 2 - device type

If device is down, or device type 3(unknown) - write in excel file:
column 1 - IP address
column 2 - result (EOF, TIMEOUT)

What I have done: I'm able to telnet to device, check device type, write in excel with 2 columns (in 1 column IP addresses, in 2 column is device type, or EOF/TIMEOUT results)
And, I'm writing full logs from session to files in format IP_ADDRESS.txt to future diagnosis.

What I can't understand to do? I can't understand how to get firmware version, and put it on 3,4 columns.
I can't understand how to work with current log session in real time, so I've decided to copy logs from main file (IP_ADDRESS.txt) to temp.txt to work with it.
I can't understand how to extract information I needed. 
The file output example:

```
    Trying 10.40.81.167...

    Connected to 10.40.81.167.

    Escape character is '^]'.



    ####################################
    #                                  #
    # RADIUS authorization disabled    #
    # Enter local login/password       #
    #                                  #
    ####################################
    bt6000 login: admin
    Password: 
    Please, fill controller information at first time (Ctrl+C to abort): 
    ^C
    Controller information filling canceled.
    ^Cadmin@bt6000# firmware info
    Active boot partition:  1
    Partition 0 (reserved):
            Firmware:       Energomera-2.3.1
            Version:        10117
    Partition 1 (active):
            Firmware:       Energomera-2.3.1_01.04.15c
            Version:        10404M
    Kernel version: 2.6.38.8 #2 Mon Mar 2 20:41:26 MSK 2015
    STM32:
            Version:        bt6000 10083
            Part Number:    BT6024
            Updated:        27.04.2015 16:43:50
    admin@bt6000#
```

I need values - after "Energomera" words, like 2.3.1 for reserved partition, and 2.3.1_01.04.15c for active partition. 
I've tried to work with string numbers and excract string, but there was not any kind of good result at all.

Full code of my script below.

```
    import pexpect
    import pxssh
    import sys          #hz module
    import re           #Parser module
    import os           #hz module
    import getopt
    import glob                     #hz module
    import xlrd                     #Excel read module
    import xlwt                     #Excel write module
    import telnetlib                #telnet module
    import shutil

    #open excel book
    rb = xlrd.open_workbook('/samba/allaccess/Energomera_Eltek_list.xlsx')
    #select work sheet
    sheet = rb.sheet_by_name('IPs')
    #rows number in sheet
    num_rows = sheet.nrows
    #cols number in sheet
    num_cols = sheet.ncols
    #creating massive with IP addresses inside
    ip_addr_list = [sheet.row_values(rawnum)[0] for rawnum in range(sheet.nrows)]
    #create excel workbook with write permissions (xlwt module)
    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
    #create sheet IP LIST with cell overwrite rights
    ws = wb.add_sheet('IP LIST', cell_overwrite_ok=True)
    #create counter
    i = 0
    #authorization details
    port = "23"                             #telnet port
    user = "admin"                         #telnet username
    password = "12345"                  #telnet password

    #firmware ask function
    def fw_info():
        print('asking for firmware')
        px.sendline('firmware info')
        px.expect('bt6000#')

    #firmware update function
    def fw_send():
        print('sending firmware')
        px.sendline('tftp server 172.27.2.21')
        px.expect('bt6000')
        px.sendline('firmware download tftp firmware.ext2')
        px.expect('Updating')
        px.sendline('y')
        px.send(chr(13))
        ws.write(i, 0, host)
        ws.write(i, 1, 'Energomera')

    #if eltek found - skip, write result in book
    def eltek_found():
        print(host, "is Eltek. Skipping")
        ws.write(i, 0, host)
        ws.write(i, 1, 'Eltek')

    #if 23 port telnet conn. refused - skip, write result in book
    def conn_refuse():
        print(host, "connection refused")
        ws.write(i, 0, host)
        ws.write(i, 1, 'Connection refused')

    #auth function
    def auth():
        print(host, "is up! Energomera found. Starting auth process")
        px.sendline(user)
        px.expect('assword')
        px.sendline(password)

    #start working with ip addresses in ip_addr_list massive
    for host in ip_addr_list:
    #spawn pexpect connection 
        px = pexpect.spawn('telnet ' + host)
        px.timeout = 35
        #create log file with in IP.txt format (10.1.1.1.txt, for example)
        fout = open('/samba/allaccess/Energomera_Eltek/{0}.txt'.format(host),"wb")
        #push pexpect logfile_read output to log file
        px.logfile_read = fout
        try:
            index = px.expect (['bt6000', 'sername', 'refused'])
            #if device tell us bt6000 - authorize        
            if index == 0:
                auth()  
                index1 = px.expect(['#', 'lease'])
                #if "#" - ask fw version immediatly
                if index1 == 0:
                    print('seems to controller ID already set')
                    fw_info()
                #if "Please" - press 2 times Ctrl+C, then ask fw version
                elif index1 == 1:
                    print('trying control C controller ID')
                    px.send(chr(3))
                    px.send(chr(3))
                    px.expect('bt6000')
                    fw_info()
    #firmware update start (temporarily off)
    #            fw_send()

    #Eltek found - func start
            elif index == 1:
                eltek_found()
    #Conn refused - func start
            elif index == 2:
                conn_refuse()
                #print output to console (test purposes)
                print(px.before)
            px.send(chr(13))
    #Copy from current log file to temp.txt for editing
            shutil.copy2('/samba/allaccess/Energomera_Eltek/{0}.txt'.format(host), '/home/bark/expect/temp.txt')
    #EOF result - skip host, write result to excel
        except pexpect.EOF:
            print(host, "EOF")
            ws.write(i, 0, host)
            ws.write(i, 1, 'EOF')
            #print output to console (test purposes)
            print(px.before)
    #Timeout result - skip host, write result to excel
        except pexpect.TIMEOUT:
            print(host, "TIMEOUT")
            ws.write(i, 0, host)
            ws.write(i, 1, 'TIMEOUT')
            #print output to console (test purposes)
            print(px.before)
            #Copy from current log file to temp.txt for editing
            shutil.copy2('/samba/allaccess/Energomera_Eltek/{0}.txt'.format(host), '/home/bark/expect/temp.txt') 
            #count +1 to correct output for Excel
        i += 1 
    #workbook save
    wb.save('/samba/allaccess/Energomera_Eltek_result.xls')
```

Have you have any suggestions or ideas, guys, how I can do this? 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

example:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> str = """
... Trying 10.40.81.167...
... 
...     Connected to 10.40.81.167.
... 
...     Escape character is '^]'.
... 
... 
... 
...     ####################################
...     #                                  #
...     # RADIUS authorization disabled    #
...     # Enter local login/password       #
...     #                                  #
...     ####################################
...     bt6000 login: admin
...     Password: 
...     Please, fill controller information at first time (Ctrl+C to abort): 
...     ^C
...     Controller information filling canceled.
...     ^Cadmin@bt6000# firmware info
...     Active boot partition:  1
...     Partition 0 (reserved):
...             Firmware:       Energomera-2.3.1
...             Version:        10117
...     Partition 1 (active):
...             Firmware:       Energomera-2.3.1_01.04.15c
...             Version:        10404M
...     Kernel version: 2.6.38.8 #2 Mon Mar 2 20:41:26 MSK 2015
...     STM32:
...             Version:        bt6000 10083
...             Part Number:    BT6024
...             Updated:        27.04.2015 16:43:50
...     admin@bt6000#
... """
>>> re.findall(r"Firmware:.*?([0-9].*)\s", str)
['2.3.1', '2.3.1_01.04.15c']

>>> reserved_firmware = re.search(r"reserved.*\s*Firmware:.*?([0-9].*)\s", str).group(1)
>>> reserved_firmware
'2.3.1'
>>> active_firmware = re.search(r"active.*\s*Firmware:.*?([0-9].*)\s", str).group(1)
>>> active_firmware
'2.3.1_01.04.15c'
>>>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you a lot! WIll look in regex manual page more, very interesting possibilities.